# Objective-C functions return types

Tags: objective-c, object, types

In c# i can create functions can return any type of objects like

```
(ArrayList) funtionName()
{
    return ArrayList;
}
```

is this possible in Obj-c?
thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can return any type of object from a function or a method in Objective-C.

Comment: So you'll know, your question has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode. Xcode is the development environment. It would be like asking how you return objects in Visual Studio when you really mean C#. I removed references to Xcode in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Objective-C can return objects, etc. although you're nearly always returning a pointer to the object.

e.g.:

```
- (NSArray *)getSomeStringsInAnArray{

    NSArray *someStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"Hello",
                            @"world",
                            nil];

    return someStrings;
}
```

I'm guessing you might want to read Apple's "[The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)" guide, as it gives a good background to such things.

Comment: Unlike C#, you can also return dynamic types: `-(id)someFunctionHere { return nil; }`